14 UNAVAILABLE: Failed to parse DNS address dns:https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf
I am trying to fetch a random Jito tip accounts using this code
async function getTipAccount() {
    const BLOCK_ENGINE_URL = "https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf";

    const searcher = searcherClient(BLOCK_ENGINE_URL, signer);

    const tipAccounts = await searcher.getTipAccounts();

    // return a random tip account
    let randomIndex = Math.random() * (tipAccounts.length - 1) + 1;
    return new PublicKey(tipAccounts[randomIndex]);
}
getTipAccount().then().catch(console.error);

But I am getting this error below
/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82
  const error = new Error(message);
                ^
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Failed to parse DNS address dns:https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf
    at callErrorFromStatus (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82:17)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:360:55)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:458:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
    at /home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:163:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:325:42)
    at ServiceClientImpl.generateAuthChallenge (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
    at AuthProvider.fullAuth (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/jito-ts/src/sdk/block-engine/auth.ts:152:17)
    at AuthProvider.injectAccessToken (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/jito-ts/src/sdk/block-engine/auth.ts:79:12)
    at Object.start (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/jito-ts/src/sdk/block-engine/auth.ts:36:22)
    at InterceptingCall.start (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:287:20)
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:326:10)
    at ServiceClientImpl.getTipAccounts (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
    at /home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/jito-ts/src/sdk/block-engine/searcher.ts:62:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  code: 14,
  details: 'Failed to parse DNS address dns:https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}


Remove https:// from the URL, make it like:
const BLOCK_ENGINE_URL = "frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf";

Perhaps there was a networking issue, this works on my side:
$ getent hosts frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf
208.91.106.46   frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf

